# I can't figure out why it's not printing the first perfect square with the last two digits that are odd

Tags: visual-c++

The professor asked us to write a program that printed the first perfect square with the last two digits being odd. Below is my attempt at the problem, I tried different ways of the code to get it it to work but to no avail. I searched around and can't seem to find anyone else with a similar assignment. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Project3.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "This program will attempt to find the first perfect square with the last two digits of the square being odd...\n";

    int i = 10;         //1. initialize "i" to 10 since square of 1 to 9 are already known to not have 2 odd last digits.
    int a = i*i;        //2. initialize "a" equal to the square of "i".
    int b = a % 100;    //3. initialize "b" to be the remainder of "a" divided by 100 (modulus operator).
    int c = b / 10;     //4. initialize "c" to be b divided by 10, which gives us the "tens" place.
    int d = a % 10;     //5. initialize "d" to be the remainder of "a" divided by 10, giving us the "ones" place.

    while (((b>10) && (b%2 != 0) && (c%2 != 0) && (d%2 != 0) && ((i*i)%i ==0)) != true){
        if ((b>10) && (b%2 != 0) && (c%2 != 0) && (d%2 != 0) && ((i*i)%i ==0)) {
        cout << "The first perfect square whose last two digits are odd is " << a << ".\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
        }   
        else {
        ++i;}
    }    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only executing once. You need a loop.

Consider:

- You run your initialization code.
- You run an if/else, which either displays output and exits, or increments `i`.
- Then you get to the end of your `main` and your program exits.

Nowhere do you say "now go back and try again with this new value of `i`". You need a `for` or a `while` in there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried putting the while loop before the if but it didn't work.

Comment: Look at your code again. Re-read your comments. Do you have things that depend on the value of `i`? Are you updating them when `i` changes?

Comment: i tried declaring the variables as global variables setting them to 0 , then setting the the while loop's statement as the i incrementer and what i previously had as the variable declarations (i.e. int a =i*i). Is this in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The following program prints out **all** perfect squares whose last two digits (in base 10) are odd:

```
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

If the last digit of n<sup>2</sup> is odd, then `n` itself must be odd, `n = 2*k + 1` for some `k`. Then

```
n^2 = (2*k + 1)^2 = 4*k*(k+1) + 1
```

is of the form `4*m + 1`. But `10 = 2*4 + 2`, so if the penultimate digit is odd, that produces a remainder of 2 modulo 4. To get a number of the form `4*m + 1`, the last digit thus must have the form `4*s + 3`, that means it must be 3 or 7. But no perfect square ends in 3 or 7. Therefore, **there is no perfect square whose last two digits (in base 10) are odd**.

Maybe your professor asked for the first perfect square whose *first* two digits are odd?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Is the formula you mentioned specific to perfect squares? As for my professor, this is the link he posted: [link](http://venus.cs.qc.edu/~waxman/211/Perfect%20square%20problem.pdf)

Comment: Which formula? `(2*k + 1)^2 = 4*k*(k+1) + 1` is a special case of `(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2*a*b  b^2` with `a = 2*k` and `b = 1` and the first two terms grouped together (`(2*k)^2 + 2*(2*k)*1 = 4*k^2 + 4*k = 4*k*(k+1)`). It's a way to see that all perfect squares have remainder 0 or 1 when divided by 4. As for the link, the task has provably no solutions. No idea whether it was meant to be a trick question or just a mistake.